# Having Trouble Proving why this is False

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$L: \mathbb{R}^{3\times3} \to  \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ is given by $L(A) = BA$ for a $3 \times 3$ matrix $B.$ If $\beta$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$, then $[L]_{\beta}=B$.

I am confused about how I am supposed to disprove or contradict this statement. I don't even know where to start with this. I know it's a linear transformation and I think if I show $L(A) \neq BA$, I can show it as false.

Comment: What does "$[L]_{\beta}$" stand for?

Comment: @Devo [L]β is the matrix representation of the linear transformation L with respect to the basis β. *i think*

Comment: @Tripping_Lettuce $L$ is an endomorphism defined on a vector space of dimension 9, so it should be represented by a matrix of size $9 \times 9$, whereas $B$ has size $3 \times 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @vizietto provides the most direct reason that the claim is false: $[L]_\beta$ and $B$ are not the same kind of object, so they cannot possibly be equal.

I want to comment on your idea for an approach. You said

> I think if I show $L(A) \neq BA$, I can show it as false.

This is not a valid way to approach this problem. In this problem, we are told that $L(A) = BA$. This is something we must assume is true! There is no way to show that $L(A) \neq BA$, because $L(A)$ and $BA$ are always equal (by assumption).

The statement that we want to show is false is

> If $\color{red}{\beta\text{ is a basis for }\mathbb{R}^{3x3}}$, then $\color{blue}{[L]_{\beta}=B}$.

This is an implication: it it says **if** $\color{red}{\text{[something]}}$ **then** $\color{blue}{\text{[something]}}$. The only way for this implication to be false is that the $\color{red}{\text{hypothesis}}$ is true but the $\color{blue}{\text{conclusion}}$ is false.

So, in order to show that this statement is false, you need to give an example of a basis $\beta$ for $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$, and then show that $[L]_\beta \neq B$ for this specific choice of $\beta$. This is, more or less, the *only* possibly way to show that this statement is false.

As @vizietto noted, any choice whatsoever will work, so the easiest thing to do is to pick the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$, and then note that $[L]_\beta$ is $9 \times 9$ while $B$ is $3 \times 3$.

Comment: Thank you! I want to 2 different prof for this problem and for some reason never got a result as simple as this.